# Unable to start Android Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am trying to make a build a simple service kinda facebook chathead but for some reason i am not able to start the service, whenever i click on the start service button nothing happens. if someone can help me here and tell me what am i doing wrong, i would really appreciate it. Thanks

FloatService.java

```
package com.example.justeen.floatexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class FloatService extends Service{

private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView floatIcon;

@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    floatIcon = new ImageView(this);
    floatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_head);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(floatIcon, params);

    try {
        floatIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatIcon, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (floatIcon != null) windowManager.removeView(floatIcon);
}
```

}

Activity.Java

```
package com.example.justeen.floatexample;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;


public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null && bundle.getString("LAUNCH").equals("YES")) {
        startService(new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, FloatService.class));

        Button launch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, FloatService.class));
            }
        });

        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, FloatService.class));
            }
        });
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hello_world, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Manifet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.justeen.floatexample" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.example.justeen.floatexample.FloatService"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What about the bundle stuff? You are adding the click listeners only if bundle != null but the app shoud not receive a bundle for its first launch unless you put it there

Comment: i wasn't sure what was that for because well i am just a beginner and i have to build a floating view service for our project so i was reusing someone else's code but i just remove the bundle stuff and tried to start the service just as is, and it somehow worked lol. thanks

Comment: I will add then the answer for you to approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the bundle check since it is kind of a copy paste without sense. When the `onCreate` is called first in the main activity, the Bundle value will be null so this is not attaching the click listeners to your service. Remove the bundle check and everything will work.